# Clausula Count(*) dentro de un select

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta SQL.

Lo que no se como hacer es que el count(*), me devuelva una columna mas, con el total de registros.

La consulta actual me bota errores, el count(*) esta entre <<>>

```
select 
    <<count(*)as count,>>
    ROW_NUMBER() over ( ORDER BY TipoPersonaId )AS RowNum, 
    * 
    from Personas 
    where TipoPersonaId=46
```

Comment: ¿Que error te da?

Comment: Es incongruente. count(*) te devolverá un sólo registro que te dirá la cantidad de registros que resulten de tu query. Row_Number te devuelve un valor por cada registro de la query. Qué esperas de resultado?

Comment: lo que necesito es que que me devuelva por ejemplo los los 10 registros con TipoPersonaId=46, pero un campo adicional donde salga 10, necesito ese "10" ese total para usarlo en otra consulta, o como lo puedo hacer... no consideren el ROW_NUMBER

Comment: `select count(*) from Personas where TipoPersonaId=46` te devolverá únicamente ese 10 que necesitas. No habrá ningún dato de ninguna fila. sólo ese 10

Comment: ¿cuál es tu motor de base de datos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No le encuentro mucho sentido a obtener en una columna el total de registros, pero dado que es lo que dices necesitar, y asumiendo que el motor de base de datos es SQL Server 2012 o superior, puedes valerte de una función de ventana para obtenerlo, por ejemplo:

```
select   count(1) over (partition by null) TotalRegistros
       , *
  from Personas
 where TipoPersonaId=46
```

pd. Asumo que es SQL server por la forma de la sentencia en la pregunta, principalmente por el uso de la función `row_number()`.

Comment: sqlserver, Good!

Comment: listo, actualicé las etiquetas de la pregunta para que quede claro el motor.

Comment: Si deseas, puedes remover la cláusula `partition by`: `select count(*) over () TotalRegistros`.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno por si alguien llega aqui buscando una respuesta, decir que cuanto se utilizan funciones agregadas de dominio como count o sum, sólo deben estar referidas a un sólo atributo de la tabla, caso contrario no funcionan.

En el caso de involucrar más de un atributo en la consulta, debe agregarse la cláusula `group`, como por ejemplo:

```
select count(*) as Productos, ReorderLevel
from dbo.Products
where dbo.Products.ProductName = 'Chai'
group by dbo.products.ReorderLevel;
<--------------!
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer 2 consultas. Una para saber la cantidad de registros, y otra para tener los datos.

```
select count(1) from Personas where TipoPersonaId=46

select * Personas where TipoPersonaId=46
```

O puedes hacer una sola consulta con una subconsulta

```
select *, (select count(1) from Personas where TipoPersonaId=46) 
from Personas 
where TipoPersonaId=46
```

Comment: Claro, pero necesito los 10 registros mas... necesito obtener los registros mas la cantidad de registros en una sola consulta, para que me retorne una sola tabla...